# Is Servlet a CDI/Managed Bean in Java EE

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, cdi, managed-bean

In a container environment (such as wildfly, jboss), are servlets treated as Managed bean? i.e. Can I inject the Servlet into any other CDI bean?

I use CdiRunner [CDI-Unit](http://bryncooke.github.io/cdi-unit/) to write my tests. And therefore I would like to inject Servlet into my Test class and test its (public) methods.

Comment: I believe a servlet is not considered a managed bean and it runs in the servlet container like a managed bean runs in the bean container.  You should however be able to inject the [servlets context](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/servlet/latest/reference/en-US/html/injectablerefs.html) into your test class?  [This](https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit/blob/master/cdi-unit/src/main/java/org/jglue/cdiunit/ContextController.java) might provide some help.

Comment: @JGlass The cdi-unit source code is a good spot. However, be careful with the other link: it points to the _old_ and _descontinued_ JBoss Seam framework documentation. I recommend the [CDI specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html) for reference instead.

Comment: @cassio-mazzochi-molin, thank you for the positive feedback and warning, I'd edit the comment if I could but it does'nt look like I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifecycle of a servlet if managed by the servlet container and not by CDI. However, CDI injection is expected to work in servlets.

A servlet container will also provide some [built-in beans](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#additional_builtin_beans) that can be injected using CDI:

> A servlet container must provide the following built-in beans, all of
>   which have qualifier `@Default`:
>
> - a bean with bean type `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`, allowing
>     injection of a reference to the `HttpServletRequest`
> - a bean with bean type `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`, allowing
>     injection of a reference to the `HttpSession`
> - a bean with bean type `javax.servlet.ServletContext`, allowing injection
>     of a reference to the `ServletContext`

If you need to inject a servlet somewhere, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Is there any documentation referring to this fact. I would like to bookmark it forever.

Comment: Dang, beat me too it!  My link might help though!